# Windows Ribbon Framework: Load resource strings from different file

Tags: winapi, ribbon, windows-ribbon-framework

I wonder if anyone knows a possibility to tell the [Windows Ribbon Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316910%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to load its resource strings from a different file (or resource handle) than the rest of the ribbon resources.

That would be important for localizing the Ribbon UI. I am aware that I can specify a different resource file at runtime dependent on the user's language, but that would mean that I need to have a copy of the ribbon markup and of all images in every localized resource DLL, although they do not change in other languages in my case. This would bloat the setup and produce extra work in keeping all those resources in sync.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible and probably also not _right_. Images **may change** for another language, same also for ribbon layout. Well it may not be _your_ case, I'd manage this externally (resources are all in the satellite files but you give out to your translators only strings - the same tool you may use to handle duplicated strings).

Comment: Things start to go downhill whenever someone tries to get clever about localizing resources. Assuming that layout or graphical resources don't need to be localized is generally wrong. You'll be digging your own hole. Historic evidence: [What was that story about the WinHelp pen-writing-in-book animation?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/17/10050774.aspx)

Comment: @Adriano: I was seeking for an optimized solution in my case. It was not my aim to tell the rest of the world how to localize their apps, I know the best practices and I fully support that the WRF allows to localize image resources. But there are thousands of projects that do not need to localize image resources and I think it is a valid to ask if there is an alternative approach with less overhead for them.

Comment: What I mean is: do not instruct ribbon to read only strings. In your DLL for resources keep everything (including layout and images because that's the way to do it and MS has absolutely no reason to support any trick to split them). Is it annoying if in your case you do not have to also localize images? Yes, use an external tool to extract them to give your translators only strings. Patch is in how you manage resources, not in how ribbon will read them...